# Invoking IBM Cloud Functions with curl results in ""The supplied authentication is invalid"

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I created a *hello world* action, could invoke it in the browser.

Invoking with curl and using the API key provided resulted in an error:

```
$ curl -u API-KEY -X POST https://us-south.functions.cloud.ibm.com/api/v1/namespaces/jps_LMI/actions/HelloWorld?blocking=true
```

> ```
> {"code":"cd01b7ea690a0454ef05016daa917bd3","error":"The supplied authentication is invalid"}
> ```

Calling the unprotected request is working fine:

```
https://us-south.functions.cloud.ibm.com/api/v1/web/jps_LMI/default/HelloWorld.json
```

Comment: Are you invoking that action as web action? Are you using a secret to protect it?

Comment: yes , I'm invoking it as web action, I think. I'm not using a particular secret, just the API key.

Comment: how did you create it? If you don't protect it, you don't provide anything. The API key is needed when invoking the action, not web action, from other environments.

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-openwhisk_webactions#securing-web-actions

Comment: I created it in the browser following the instructions on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y24yR9Jg1s and then tried curl. some things look different, so there have been some changes, perhaps. I didn't notice anything about protecting so far.